# При добавлении фото через UIImagePickerController происходит ошибка

Tags: ios, swift, изображения, uitableview, parse.com

Извините что повторюсь.Но если ли серьезные люди, и если собрались помочь до проверяйте сообщения и доведите дело конца .У меня в хедере находиться изображение, пытаюсь добавить фото, а оно не появляется в изображении.И выдает такую ошибку

> [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error
>   Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Я уже эту функцию Пикера в делегат добавил в метод viewDidLoad. Ошибка не уходит , уже много примеров просмотрел.Все равно  не уходит  ошибка.Вот мой код.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class UserProfile: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    var myUser = [PFUser.current()]

@objc func updatePhoto() {
        let myPickerImageController = UIImagePickerController()
       myPickerImageController.delegate = self
        myPickerImageController.allowsEditing = false
        myPickerImageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerImageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ProfileUserHeaderView") as! ProfileUserHeaderView

           let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
           header.userFot.image = image
          savePhoto(image:image )

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
   @objc func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

  var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white)
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Обновление")

        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
            #selector(UserProfile.handleRefresh(_:)),
                                 for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.universalColorYellow

        return refreshControl
    }()







    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updatePhoto()

        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;

        activityIndicator.center = view.center;
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "ProfileUserHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "ProfileUserHeaderView")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Сохранить", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveBarItem))
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.universalColorYellow
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Назад"

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.reloadData()
        loadEditUserInfo()

       // loadObjectUser()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        }

 /*
func loadObjectUser() {

   PFUser.current()!.fetchInBackground(block: { (currentUser, error) -> Void in
        if let user = currentUser as? PFUser {
            user.fetchFromLocalDatastoreInBackground()

        }
    })
} */



    func segueUser() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "userprofile", sender: self)

    }




    @objc func saveBarItem() {
        activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        let user = PFUser.current()!
        let indexOne = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
         let indexTwo = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
         let indexThree = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
         let indexFour = IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)
        let cellOne : UserEditTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexOne) as! UserEditTableViewCell
        let cellTwo : UserEditTableViewCellTwo = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexTwo) as! UserEditTableViewCellTwo
        let cellThree : UserEditTableViewCellThree = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexThree) as! UserEditTableViewCellThree
        let cellFour : UserEditTableViewCellFour = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexFour) as! UserEditTableViewCellFour
         let username = cellOne.userTextField.text!
         let country = cellTwo.countryTextfield.text!
        let email = cellThree.emailTextField.text!
        let password = cellFour.passwordTextField.text!
        user["username"] = username
        user["country"] = country
        user["email"] = email
        user["password"] = password

           if PFUser.current()?.password == "" {
            self.alert(message: "Введите пароль", title: "BRAVOBET")

        } else {

     user.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        Alert.show(textTitle: "BRAVOBET", text: "Вы успешно изменили данные", view: self)
                        self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.dismiss(animated: true , completion: nil)
            } else {
               print("Error")

            }
        })
        }
    }

    func savePhoto(image:UIImage) {
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)!
        let imageFile = PFFile(data: imageData)

        // Upload to Open Source Parse Server which stores the image in an Amazon S3 bucket.
       let userImage = PFUser.current()!
        userImage.setObject(imageFile!, forKey: "profile_picture")
        userImage.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
            if success {

                print("Добавление фото прошло успешо")
            }
        }
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ProfileUserHeaderView") as! ProfileUserHeaderView

        header.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250)
        header.username.text = PFUser.current()!.username

         header.buttonSave.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updatePhoto), for: .touchUpInside)
      //  header.bravoBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProfileUserHeaderView.likeBtn(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        if  header.userFot.image != nil {
            header.userFot.image = UIImage(named: "noFoto")
        } else {

            let imagePro: PFFile = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "profile_picture") as! PFFile;
            imagePro.getDataInBackground { (data, error) in
                header.userFot.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
            }
        }

        return header
    }




   @IBAction func userSegue(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pushToUser", sender: self)

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 250
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       if  indexPath.row == 0  {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellOne") as! UserEditTableViewCell
        cell.userTextField.text = PFUser.current()!.username

           return cell
       } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTwo") as! UserEditTableViewCellTwo
        cell.countryTextfield.text = PFUser.current()!["country"] as? String

        return cell
       } else if indexPath.row == 2 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellThree") as! UserEditTableViewCellThree
        cell.emailTextField.text = PFUser.current()!.email

        return cell
       } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellFour") as! UserEditTableViewCellFour
        cell.passwordTextField.text = PFUser.current()!.password

       return cell
        }


    }

    @objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


    func alert(message: NSString, title: NSString) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title as String, message: message as String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func loadEditUserInfo() {

        let userInformation = PFQuery(className: "User")

        userInformation.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objectUser, error) in

            if (objectUser != nil) {

                self.myUser = objectUser! as! [PFUser]
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()


            })
            }

        })

    }


}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выдает ошибку при добавлении или изменении фото через UIImagePickerController?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872078/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myPickerImageController.allowsEditing = false

Замените на

myPickerImageController.allowsEditing = true